# "the timing of something" or "the timing of the something"

Tags: grammar, articles

I have a question about these sentences:

(1) "This may impact the timing of the application submission."

(2) "This may impact timing of the application submission."

(3) "This may impact the timing of application submission."

Which is correct?

The reader understands which specific application is used.

My hunch is (2)? Timing refers to when, so there is no specific timing. The submission is specific, so it needs to have an article.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are choices 1 and 3 different?

Comment: @YosefBaskin It is now ! : ) a typo..!

Comment: Include both definite articles. 'Timing' is given sufficient specificity (even if the actual time is unclear) to warrant the definite article. Even 'The Hunting of the Snark' gets two.